# Change color median line ggplot geom_boxplot()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to change the color of the median line in `geom_boxplot()`. I have looked and can't find a way to do it. I have posted the R code here that I am using but I just really need a reference to how to change the color.

```
ggplot(invitro2) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = reorder(CANCER_TYPE,tmedian), y = GeoMedian_IC50)) +
  xlab("") +  
  geom_point(aes(x = reorder(CANCER_TYPE,tmedian), y = GeoMedian_IC50)) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) +
  annotation_logticks(sides="l")   +  
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45,size=10,hjust=1),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank())
```

Comment: and you `dput(head(invitro2, 10))` ?

Answer (score 19):

You can use the details of the plot, to derive the coordinates of where the median line is, and then add colour to it using `geom_segment`.

```
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(am), mpg)) + geom_boxplot()

dat <- ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]

p + geom_segment(data=dat, aes(x=xmin, xend=xmax, 
                               y=middle, yend=middle), colour="red", size=2)
```

Also had to increase the `size` of the line so that it covers the original black median
line

[image]

Comment: how to perform it in a faceted geom_boxplot()?

Comment: @WilsonSouza ; append the faceting variable to `dat`. A quick example; `p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(am), mpg)) + geom_boxplot() + facet_wrap(~cyl) ; dat <- ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]  dat <- cbind(dat, cyl=sort(unique(mtcars$cyl))[dat$PANEL])` If your facetting variable is a factor you should use `levels` instead of the `sort(unique())`. But this answer is ~6.5 years old, and there may now be better ways to do this.

Comment: What about if you have multiple boxplots at each `x` value in a faceted `geom_boxplot` ?

Comment: Can you give an example please @Jared, similar to example in my comment above,

Comment: A fake dataframe in the same format as the data I am working with - `df_fish <- data.frame(
  Fish_Group =
    factor(rep(c(
      "Bluegill", "Minnow", "Pike"
    ),
    each = 27)),
  Label = factor(c(
    rep(c("BG1", "BG2", "BG3"), each = 3,
        times = 3),
    rep(c("MN1", "MN2",
          "MN3"), each = 3,
        times = 3),
    rep(c("P1", "P2", "P3"), each = 3, times = 3)
  )),
  Measure_Type = factor(rep(
    c("Longest Side", "Hypotenuse", "Arc Length"), each = 1
  )),
  Length = c(
    runif(27, 8, 12),
    runif(27, 8, 12),
    runif(27, 25, 35)
  )
)`

Comment: Fake plot to try and replace the median with a different color line - `df_fish %>%
  group_by(Fish_Group,
           Label,
           Measure_Type) %>%
  ggplot(data = ., aes(x = Label, y = Length)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Measure_Type), size = 0.25, color = "black") +
  facet_grid(~ Fish_Group, scales = "free_x")`

Comment: Now I have each level of `Measure_Type` at each `Label` with the plot faceted by `Fish_Group`.

Comment: @Jared; a quick look seems that the approach in the earlier comment still works. The only difference is you are using some grouping. I'd thus split it into; `plot_dat = df_fish %>%   group_by(Fish_Group,  Label, Measure_Type)` . Then your plot code saved into an object: `p <- plot_dat %>% ggplot(data = .  ....and so on)`. Match in panel data: `dat <- ggplot_build(p)$data [[1]] ; dat <- cbind(dat, Fish_Group=levels(plot_dat$Fish_Group)[dat$PANEL])` . The add segments: `p + geom_segment(data=dat, aes(x=xmin, xend=xmax, y=middle, yend=middle), colour="red", linewidth=2)`

Comment: Yup, it does work. I was making a mistake with my actual dataframe, but got it working on my real data now. Thanks!!