# Change Median Color geom_boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, median

Is there a command to Change the colour of the median line in boxplots that were produced using ggplot2/geom_boxplot?

Comment: A kind of roundabout solution is provided here [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002257/change-color-median-line-ggplot-geom-boxplot)

Answer (score 3):

if you want to change the colour of all lines, you can use this:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(class, hwy))+ geom_boxplot(colour = "red")
```

if you just want to change the colour of the median, you can use the answer from here:

[Change color median line ggplot geom_boxplot()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002257/change-color-median-line-ggplot-geom-boxplot)

it adds a layer with `geom_segment`